# WebAPI Multi Route

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I added 2 route, the following is my code

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "HandheldApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/handheld/{controller}/{action}"
        );
```

When I use the following link http://localhost:64886/api/Account/Get, this link is work for me
But I use the following link http://localhost:64886/api/handheld/Account/Get, the server return "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI"

How can I do? I must set 2 route because the new route is new mapping, the default route will be obsoleted

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the `defaults` parameter for your second route. Hope this will work-

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "HandheldApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/handheld/{controller}/{action}"
        defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyMethod" }
    );
```